# Deferred: Name server: gmail.com.: host name lookup failure

Tags: ubuntu, smtp, sendmail

I'm using zf with smtp of google on my localmachine, the server takes too long, then Checking the log message I get the following:

```
mymachinename sm-mta[20775]: q89DwF0X020757: to=<myaccountname@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<XXXXX@localhost.local> (1000/1000), delay=00:00:40, xdelay=00:00:20, mailer=esmtp, pri=120528, relay=gmail.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Name server: gmail.com.: host name lookup failure
```

SMTP config:

```
mail.smtp.host= "smtp.gmail.com"
mail.smtp.auth= "login"
mail.smtp.username="myusername@gmail.com"
mail.smtp.password="password"
mail.smtp.port="465"
mail.smtp.ssl="tls"
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: The error message is unrelated to your code. Your DNS server is not working, or is refusing your queries, or is blocking gmail specifically, or you are offline.

Comment: That makes sense, I changed the email in the to: to a different one @ a different domain, it said the same about that domain. I also faced a problem with connecting to remote servers with filezilla only by IP, hostnames doesn't resolve either. But everything else is working smoothly such as the package manager, adding ppa's...etc, can you suggest a path I can take to resolve this issue

Comment: Off-topic for SO anyway.  I suggest you nominate for moving to Super User.